Why are `_parent_pid` and `_parent_name` attributes of class BaseProcess(object) in multiprocessing/process.py assigned with current info?
According to the multiprocessing/process.py file for Python 3.10.12:
class BaseProcess(object):
    '''
    Process objects represent activity that is run in a separate process

    The class is analogous to `threading.Thread`
    '''
    def _Popen(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={},
                 *, daemon=None):
        assert group is None, 'group argument must be None for now'
        count = next(_process_counter)
        self._identity = _current_process._identity + (count,)
        self._config = _current_process._config.copy()
        self._parent_pid = os.getpid()
        self._parent_name = _current_process.name
        self._popen = None
        self._closed = False
        self._target = target
        self._args = tuple(args)
        self._kwargs = dict(kwargs)
        self._name = name or type(self).__name__ + '-' + \
                     ':'.join(str(i) for i in self._identity)
        if daemon is not None:
            self.daemon = daemon
        _dangling.add(self)

May I know why lines 86 & 87 write this:
self._parent_pid = os.getpid()
self._parent_name = _current_process.name 

and not
self._parent_pid = os.getppid()
self._parent_name = _parent_process.name  

Meaning, should not the parent info instead of the current info be used for the parent attributes?

It is spawning a new process. Why would a parent pid of a new process current pid is spawning be the parent pid of the current process?

@KamilCuk Isn't the new process spawned by another/different (i.e. parent) process? Should not the one that is doing the spawning be called the parent? Or do you mean a process can spawn more processes from itself, like cloning itself? I am interested to understand the logic of how multiprocess works, hence my question.

(i.e. parent) process? It is spawned by the python process, that is executing right now. be called the parent? I have a parent, and my parent also has a parent. Both are parents. The parent of the new process is the current process. itself, like cloning itself? Every process can spawn multiple processes, on linux first process does fork() then exec() -research fork and exec if you are interested - but these are implementation details. I fail to understand your confusion. If I have a child, why would my child parent be my parent? The parent of my child is me.

@KamilCuk The parent of my child is me. I see. Then, am I correct to think that self._identity = _current_process._identity + (count,) is how the child's identity is created different to me?


Why are _parent_pid and _parent_name attributes of class BaseProcess(object) in multiprocessing/process.py assigned with current info?

Because the current process is spawning a new process.

should not the parent info instead of the current info be used for the parent attributes?

No. Additionally, Python is used in millions of projects. It is safe to assume that with high probability what is in the standard python library is correct.
